# data providers in testng using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

```
    @DataProvider
    public Iterator<String> getTestData() throws  IOException

    {
        ReadTestData readtestData=new ReadTestData();
        ArrayList<String> testData=readtestData.readExcel();    
        return testData.iterator();
    }


    @Test(dataProvider="getTestData")
    public void addEmployeeExcel(String empRef,String foreName,String surName,String jobTitle,String location)
    {
    System.out.println("empref"+empRef);

    }
```

why am I getting below error? I have 5 columns in excel sheet

> Data provider mismatch Method: addEmployeeExcel([Parameter{index=0,
>   type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1,
>   type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2,
>   type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3,
>   type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}]) Arguments:
>   [(java.lang.String) WTS1]

Comment: Maybe you can print your testData and check out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getTestData()` method returns a collection of `String` but your `addEmployeeExcel()` method takes 5 `String` parameters. You need to change the parameters of `addEmployeeExcel()` to take the collection and then extract each variable, `empRef`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check arguments of testData and pass accordingly for addEmployeeExcel method,

If you don't know, What testData is having, You can Print it in console.

**Sample Code:**

```
@DataProvider
public Iterator<Object[]> getTestData()
{
    ArrayList<Object[]> testdata = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    try {
        reader = new excelUtility(excelTestDataFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sheetName = "namingTest";
    for (int rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= reader.getRowCount(sheetName); rowNumber++) 
    {
        String caseNo = reader.getCellData(sheetName, "Case", rowNumber);
        String groupName = reader.getCellData(sheetName, "Name", rowNumber);
        String message = reader.getCellData(sheetName, "Expected Result", rowNumber);

        Object ob[] =
        { caseNo, groupName, message };
        testdata.add(ob);
    }
    return testdata.iterator();
}
```

And Here is Test method,

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getTestData")
public void addGroup(String caseNo, String targetGroupName, String expectedResult) throws Exception {
    }
```

Comment: It is an Object of class excelUtility, In which Excel Retrieve code is there.

Comment: Is excelUtility  a user defined class?

Comment: Yes ! User defined method to retrieve excel data

Comment: nope, There are more than 200+ line of code. You need to just check on testData return value.